# How to compare inner for iterator with outer for iterator

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have the template code set up as :

```
{% for f in fs %}
{
            name: '{{f.fname}}',
            data: [{% for items in frequencydata %}
                    {% if {{forloop.parentloop.counter}}=={{forloop.counter}} %}
                       {% for item in items %}
                         {{ item}},
                       {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
                   {% endfor %}
]
        },
{% endfor %}
```

I am getting "Could not parse" error in

```
{% if {{forloop.parentloop.counter}}=={{forloop.counter}} %}
```

What is the correct method to do this?

More info:

I have two lists

```
fs ['a','b','c']

frequencydata [[[1990,5],[1991,6]]  ,   [[1990,15],[1991,16]]  ,   [[1990,25],[1991,26]]]
```

The data is corresponding between lists based on position and I need to display them together.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't include the curly braces when using a variable inside a template tag:

```
{% if forloop.parentloop.counter == forloop.counter %}
```

Including `{{f.fname}}` doesn't make sense if fs is the list `['a', 'b', 'c']`. Those strings don't have an `fname` attribute.

Finally, including `{{ item}},` means that the final item in the array will have a trailing comma, which is invalid.

You might find it easier to create the object in python, use [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to convert it to json, and pass it to your template.